# Alexa Voice Service response returns 0 bytes for V1 speechrecognizer API

Tags: java, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to get the V1 speechrecognizer API working with my java client but I think I'm missing something as I am unable to get any response from AVS for my POST request. The entire code snippet is shown below.

Hoping someone can point out my mistake.

Here is the main function for my app:

```
public class App 
{
    private static String requestURL = "https://access-alexa-na.amazon.com/v1/avs/speechrecognizer/recognize";

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    try {

    MultipartUtility mpu = new MultipartUtility(requestURL, "UTF-8", AvsRequest.getToken(), AvsRequest.getBoundary());
        mpu.addRequestStart();
        mpu.addData("tts_hello_how_are_you_doing_today.wav");
        mpu.addRequestEnd();
        mpu.finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This is a utility method for the request body:

```
public class AvsRequest {
private static final String BOUNDARY = "BOUNDARY1234";
private static final String BOUNDARY_DASHES = "--";
private static final String NEWLINE = "\r\n";
private static final String METADATA_CONTENT_DISPOSITION = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"metadata\"";
private static final String METADATA_CONTENT_TYPE="Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8";
private static final String AUDIO_CONTENT_TYPE="Content-Type: audio/L16; rate=16000; channels=1";
private static final String AUDIO_CONTENT_DISPOSITION="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"audio\"";

private static final String METADATA="{\"messageHeader\": {\"deviceContext\":[{\"name\":\"playbackState\", \"namespace\":\"AudioPlayer\", \"payload\":{\"streamId\":\"\", \"offsetInMilliseconds\":\"0\", \"playerActivity\":\"IDLE\"}}]},\"messageBody\": {\"profile\": \"alexa-close-talk\",\"locale\": \"en-us\",\"format\": \"audio/L16; rate=16000; channels=1\"}}";

private static final String TOKEN = "Atza|I....";

public static String getRequestStart(){

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.append(BOUNDARY_DASHES);
    str.append(BOUNDARY);
    str.append(NEWLINE);
    str.append(METADATA_CONTENT_DISPOSITION);
    str.append(NEWLINE);
    str.append(METADATA_CONTENT_TYPE);
    str.append(NEWLINE);
    str.append(NEWLINE);
    str.append(METADATA);
    str.append(NEWLINE);
    str.append(NEWLINE);
    str.append(BOUNDARY_DASHES);
    str.append(BOUNDARY);
    str.append(NEWLINE);
    str.append(AUDIO_CONTENT_DISPOSITION);
    str.append(NEWLINE);
    str.append(AUDIO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    str.append(NEWLINE);

    return str.toString();
}

public static String getRequestEnd(){

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.append(NEWLINE);
    str.append(NEWLINE);
    str.append(BOUNDARY_DASHES);
    str.append(BOUNDARY);
    str.append(BOUNDARY_DASHES);
    str.append(NEWLINE);

    return str.toString();
}

public static String getBoundary() {
    return BOUNDARY;
}

public static String getToken() {
    return TOKEN;
}
}
```

And this is the Multipart request class:

```
public class MultipartUtility {

private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
private String charset;
private OutputStream outputStream;
private PrintWriter writer;
private String oauth2Token;
private URL url;


public MultipartUtility(String requestURL, String charset, String token, String boundary) throws IOException {


    this.charset = charset;
    this.oauth2Token = token;
    this.url = new URL(requestURL);

    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " +token);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

    outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),false);

}

public void addRequestStart(){
writer.append(AvsRequest.getRequestStart());
writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append("\r\n");
    System.out.println("POST REQUEST START: \n" + AvsRequest.getRequestStart());

}    

public void addData(String fileName) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        writer.write(buffer.toString());
    }
    writer.flush();
    inputStream.close();
}



public void addRequestEnd(){

writer.append(AvsRequest.getRequestEnd());
System.out.println("POST REQUEST END: " +AvsRequest.getRequestEnd());
writer.flush();
writer.close();
}

public void finish1() throws IOException {
    InputStream response = null;
    try {
    writer.close();
    response = httpConn.getInputStream();
    System.out.println("Response Size:\n"+ response.available());
    OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("response.txt"));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));
    String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            fos.write(line.getBytes());
            fos.flush();
        }
        reader.close();
        fos.close();
        httpConn.disconnect();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar result when sending an audio format that is incorrect for the Alexa Voice Service.  In testing the audio file being sent to the https, I used Audacity to format and test the audio in mono and 16000 hz, which then returned a valid response.  Sending an audio in stereo seems to return a zero byte result.